# How can I add "add to cart button" in custom phtml file?

Tags: magento2

How can I add **"add to cart button"** in my custom phtml file in Magento 2 ?

Please describe how default Magento 2 add to cart button working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can add button in custom phtml file as follow, I have done this in custom module

In your block file

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
<?php
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $listProductBlock,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->listProductBlock = $listProductBlock;
    }

public function getProductCollection()
{
    /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
   $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    return $collection;
}
public function getAddToCartPostParams($product)
{
    return $this->listProductBlock->getAddToCartPostParams($product);
}
?>
```

get productlist in view file

```
<?php 
const PARAM_NAME_BASE64_URL = 'r64';
const PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED = 'uenc';
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action; 
$_productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
    <?php echo $_product->getName()?>
    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <?php $storeManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'); ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                    class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
            </button>
    </form>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
<?php $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
?>
<button class="action tocart primary"
        data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>'
        type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart1') ?>">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
```

Where $_item is your product.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate this was nearly 2 years ago but this has worked perfectly for me, is there any way to adjust the quantity?

Comment: not working. 
Click on Add To Cart button nothing happen

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in your phtml file for add to cart button

```
  <?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

  $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

  $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product); ?>

  <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>

     <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">

       <span>Add to Cart</span>
     </button>
 </form>
```

Comment: This is works well for simple products but when is configurable with variation it add to cart but it has no details in the mini-cart do you know a fix for this. thanks

Comment: How does $product get defined?