# Add product to cart programatically and update shopping cart using block and template file in Magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, magento-2.0.7

I have to add product from home page using custom module. so how to add products in shopping cart by clicking Add to cart button.

Please anyone help me

Comment: custom product ? product with custom option ?

Comment: Not like that Sir. I mentioned what i need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add "add to cart button" in custom phtml file?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98634/how-can-i-add-add-to-cart-button-in-custom-phtml-file)

Comment: It's not duplicate. The given solution is only working for add to cart button but it's not working for update shopping cart box. I want if pressed add to cart button then same time it should update shopping cart. but here shopping is not increasing

Comment: What happens when you try to add again product that already exists in cart ? some error ?or ?

Comment: What you have done so far ? Please share the code

Comment: [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98634/how-can-i-add-add-to-cart-button-in-custom-phtml-file] , I used this. It's working fine but it's not updating cart. When we go at checkout page, at that page  it's shopping. My requirement is when customer click addtocart button then they know about the addition of product.