# Add-to-cart button for all products on detail page

Tags: magento2, addtocart, product-view

I want to add `add to cart` button in third party module **.phtml** file same as `add to cart` works on detail page.

There are different product-type like `grouped product` and I want `add-to-cart` button on all products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to override default magento block :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php.
```

**=> Link :**

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122897

Comment: i visited that link before this but i want add that button in third party extension detail page.
i link is given by you it's used for override to theme category list page and i want to use add to cart button at third party extension.