# What is the best way to create custom theme in magento 2.2?

Tags: magento2.2, custom-theme

Which files I should copied from the Luma theme to Custom theme?

When I create my custom theme - `review section` and `add to cart` in product view page are not working.

If I copies `Magento_Review` module review section will work.

**but how to solve add to cart issue in product page?**

Please anyone explain me what is the issue and solution?

Comment: Can you please tell me whats the exact issue ?

Comment: Magento Add to cart function not working in product page only

Comment: have you found any error in console.log or browser's log ?

Comment: please explain in details like "button click not working" etc...

Comment: No,I think We need to override some module into my custom theme....Like review module

Comment: add to cart button is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68688/discussion-between-aasim-goriya-and-ranganathan-s).

Answer (score 0):

Please override the checkout module

> Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

Comment: I need explanation sir...What is the relation between Checkout module and add to cart ....And why addtocart is not working?Can you please explain

Comment: I think this link will help you more https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98634/how-can-i-add-add-to-cart-button-in-custom-phtml-file