# How to create custom Add to cart button and functionality

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, addtocart

I'm working with magento2. I have created popup  and display cart product of related products. Now I want create custom Add to cart button for related products. So after add to cart product  I want manage at my end and redirect on checkout page. I want added cart of data. And redirect on custom url. 
It is possible with without observer in magento2.

Comment: Hope this might help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98634/how-can-i-add-add-to-cart-button-in-custom-phtml-file

Comment: I have added button but I want my button will work without ajax and also how can I manage after add to cart, I want redirect on custom page after add to cart.