# Magento 2: Add to cart button issue on phtml file (Ajax base add to cart Prodcut )

Tags: magento2, ajaxaddtocart

I have added the code for add to cart button but i don't want to refresh the page when i click on button. How to achieve this?

I need the functionality as like default add to cart button(product detail page).

Here is my code:

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

  $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

  $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product); ?>

  <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post"> 

    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>

     <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">

       <span>Add to Cart</span>
     </button>
 </form>
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98634/how-can-i-add-add-to-cart-button-in-custom-phtml-file

Comment: But i want to add in custom theme not in module

Comment: themename\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\product_description

Comment: yes this is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add this script to your phtml.

```
   <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "product_sku": "<?php echo  /* @NoEscape */ 
                        $product->getSku() ?>"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```